# (How) can I call some function which return type is not bool in AND expression?

Tags: c++

For example I got two function:

```
void beforeTest();
bool test();
```

and I want to use them like this:

```
if(beforeTest() && test()) {...}
```

Assume that I cannot call `beforeTest()` before `if`, and `test()`'s value depends on the side effect of `beforeTest()`, is there any way I can put them in the same AND expression like above?

Comment: "Assume that I cannot call beforeTest() before if" why? if `beforeTest()` returns `void` then your attempted code is the same as `beforeTest(); if (test()) { }`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Right now, without further context, this sounds to me like you want to do something you really should not do.

Comment: the problem is that one can conclude anything from a wrong assumption ;) Maybe this is a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve by including the call to `beforeTest` in the if condition?

Comment: It's complicated to explain, I have to do this because some legacy code, and I have got what I want, thanks all.

Comment: I only can imagine that this is a metaprogramming problem, where code is generated by macro. In any other case, any solution equals in call before if(). Actually test() is called before the check, check performed on temporal value returned. That's how generated code works. C++ got better ways to create metacode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really need to call it inside the condition, which you probably should not, you can use the comma operator.

```
if (beforeTest(), test()) ...
```

Comment: this comma syntax can be used in any expressions, right?

Comment: @reavenisadesk almost, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other